# AutoIT getting class of the element

Tags: class, autoit

i have problem, i know the ID of the element and i want to get it's class.
I know that his ID is "js_GlobalMenu_military" and his class has few variables it can be "premiumalert","premium" and few others. I tried everything. Is there a function which returns class of the element?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

For example, to start sending an email in Gmail I know of one class (this would work with the ID you have as well) for the compose button:

```
$oComposeButton = $oIE.document.querySelector('.T-I-KE')
```

Taking that I can get the classList and iterate through to get the other classes:

```
$oComposeClasses = $oComposeButton.classList

For $i = 0 To ($oComposeClasses.length - 1) Step 1
     MsgBox(64,"Class Index "  & $i, $oComposeClasses.item($i))
Next
```